# Putting Date Entry VBA effect in two different range of cells in same worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put the fixed date format to my Excel sheet and used below VBA code for a date column B. It worked perfectly but I still need to do exactly like this in another column (let's say in column E). But I don't know how to put this effect on another range of cells (in column E). Any idea and suggestion on it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DateStr As String

On Error GoTo EndMacro
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B1048576")) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
If .HasFormula = False Then
Select Case Len(.Formula)
    Case 4 ' e.g., 9298 = 2-Sep-1998
        DateStr = Mid(.Formula, 2, 1) & "/" & _
        Left(.Formula, 1) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 2)
    Case 5 ' e.g., 11298 = 12-Jan-1998 NOT 2-Nov-1998
        DateStr = Mid(.Formula, 2, 2) & "/" & _
        Left(.Formula, 1) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 2)
    Case 6 ' e.g., 090298 = 2-Sep-1998
        DateStr = Mid(.Formula, 3, 2) & "/" & _
        Left(.Formula, 2) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 2)
    Case 7 ' e.g., 1231998 = 23-Jan-1998 NOT 3-Dec-1998
        DateStr = Mid(.Formula, 2, 2) & "/" & _
        Left(.Formula, 1) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 4)
    Case 8 ' e.g., 09021998 = 2-Sep-1998
        DateStr = Mid(.Formula, 3, 2) & "/" & _
        Left(.Formula, 2) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 4)
    Case Else
        Err.Raise 0
End Select
.Formula = DateValue(DateStr)
End If

End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EndMacro:
MsgBox "You did not enter a valid date."
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `"B4:B1048576"` to `"E4:E1048576"` at the beginning.

Comment: I think if i changed like this, the code will only effect to `"Column E"` and will stop working on `"Column B"`. Is that you mean?

Comment: Yes. You want to alter both coluns at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I need to do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
If Application.Intersect(Target, Union(Range("B4:B1048576"),Range("E4:E1048576"))) Is Nothing Then
'rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple than Union I think

```
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D1048576,E2:E1048576,etc...as much 
column names as you want")) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If
```